# How to handle error response with retrofit + coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

I'm new with coroutines. Trying to use retrofit + coroutines + Jake Wharton's CoroutineCallAdapterFactory by [this tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-networking-in-2019-retrofit-with-kotlins-coroutines-aefe82c4d777)

But don't get how to handle json response errors. For example error could be like that:

```
{
  "code": 105,
  "error": "invalid field name: bl!ng"
}
```

I think adding *code* and *error* fields (and checking object for null fields) in *TmdbMovie* class - it's wrong.
And then - how to use error fields after launching coroutine in *TmdbViewModel* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`try/catch` the `await` as recommended by @JakeWharton in this [issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter/issues/3)

```
try {
    youService().await()
} catch(ex: HttpException) {
    // do your handling here
}
```

Comment: putting all exceptions at Activity/View level ? Is there's another way here ?

Comment: @ralphgabb unfortunately, I haven't followed up the case

Comment: But what if the server sends an error message that you would like to display the user? When I'm not wrong, the received error message wouldn't be available in the catch.

Comment: @Vega180, catching the HttpException will allow you to grab the error response from the server (in our case, comes in JSON format).  `ex.errorBody()?.toString()`.  Then just use your favorite JSON serializer / deserializer library to parse to an object if you like.  I also recommend catching other exceptions as well (such as `SocketTimeoutException`, `UnknownHostException`, etc) to provide more feedback if necessary.  For instance, a 5xx error will not come back as an `HttpException` and you would want to handle accordingly.